# django function inside models, display result inside the template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models as given below.

```
PRODUCT_TYPE=(('TL','Tubeless Tyre'), ('TT','Tubed Tyre'), ('NA','Not applicable'))
class Product(models.Model):
    product_group=models.ForeignKey('productgroup.ProductGroup', null=False,blank=False)
    manufacturer=models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=False,blank=False)
    product_type=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE,)

    opening_stock=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s, %s, %s) o.stock = %d ' % (self.product_group, self.manufacturer, self.product_type ,self.opening_stock)

        unique_together = ('product_group', 'manufacturer','product_type')
    def get_total_stock_in(self):
        Stock.objects.filter(product=self.id,ttype='I').aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
    def get_total_stock_out(self):
        Stock.objects.filter(product=self.id,ttype='I').aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
```

and

```
TRANSACTION_TYPE=(('I','Stock In'),('O','Stock Out'))
class Stock(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey('product.Product', blank=False,null=False)
    date=models.DateField(blank=False, null=False,)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    ttype=models.CharField(max_length=1,verbose_name="Ttransaction type",choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE, blank=False)
    added_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', args=[str(self.product.id)])
    def __str__(self):
        return ('[%s] %s (%s) %d' %(self.product, self.date, self.ttype, self.quantity))
```

and a view

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    model=Product
```

My intention is to have two `functions get_total_stock_in()` and `functions get_total_stock_out()` to find the sum of all stock_ins and stock_outs for each product and display the result in the template `product_list.html`

For this, I have

```
<ul>
        {% for product in object_list %}
            <li><a href="{%url 'product_detail' product.id %}">{{ product.product_group}}-{{ product.product_type}}
                {{ product.manufacturer}} </a>
                opening.stock: <b>{{ product.opening_stock}} </b>, 
                total s/i: {{product.get_total_stock_in.quantity__sum}} ,
                total s/o: {{product.get_total_stock_out.quantity__sum}}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I don't know how to get the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have, apart from using type I instead of O in the get_total_stock_out method? What happens when you try this code?

Comment: I get the output as blank

Comment: If you have another question you should ask it as a new question complete with what you have tried and researched

Comment: @Sayse sorry, here all the models are same. So, I thought it's okay to add it here.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman 
In the shell, I get the following output. 

>>> Stock.objects.filter(product=1,ttype='O').aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
{'quantity__sum': 3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods do not actually return anything - they calculate the sums, but then throw them away. Python requires an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!